# Can't keep field empty even if it is set to null and blank

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Model:

```
class Member( models.Model ):

    model_categories = models.CharField(
            max_length = 255,
            null = True,
            blank = True )
```

Form:

```
class MemberForm( forms.ModelForm ):

    MODEL_CATEGORIES = (
        ('advisor', 'advisor'),
        ('member', 'member'),
        ('admin', 'admin'),
    )


    model_categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices = MODEL_CATEGORIES
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = [ 'model_categories' ]
```

Still when I submit the form, it requires the field `model_categories` that can't have no box selected. What is the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#required):

> Field.required¶
>   By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you pass an empty value – either None or the empty string ("") – then clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:

So you have to set required false to your field

```
model_categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices = MODEL_CATEGORIES
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields in django forms are `required=True` by default. Set `required=False` in your form field definition:

```
model_categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices = MODEL_CATEGORIES,
            required=False
    )
```

More:

`blank=True` in the model is deciding weather the field can be blank or not in the form.

**But**, by defining the field in your `MemberForm`

```
model_categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices = MODEL_CATEGORIES
```

you are overiding the field from `ModelForm` where requried attribute is set `False` by model `blank=True`, using default attribute `required=True`from the new field definition.